# Bind macro to excel cell onclick?

Tags: excel, events, vba

In excel 2000, is it possible to bind a vba function to be executed when a cell is clicked with the mouse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution:

Make a named range for the cells you want to capture clickevent

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = Target.Address
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("MyNamedRange")) Is Nothing Then 
        ' do your stuff
        Range("A1").Select
    Endif
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You can bind to a cell double click.

Open VBA, goto the worksheet you want to wire up the event
Select WorkSheet in the dropdown on the top left and BeforeDoubleClick in the top right
The check the Target.Address is equal to the address of the cell you care about and call the function you wish.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Address(True, True, xlA1) = "$A$1" Then
        Call MyDemo
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyDemo()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: double click is good enough for me. great answer. Can the beforeX functions actually cancel the default event processing?

Comment: I think so. Set Cancel to true I believe - but have never tried!

Comment: hehe. beat me to it by 30 secs. Just found in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220840%28office.11%29.aspx. Cancel = True works just great.